# All applications quit when printing on Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: mac, printing, updates, osx-leopard

I recently ran a software update.  I'm not sure if my problems are associated with this but I'm pretty sure they are as I printed successfully before update.

I checked the log at time of printing:

```
03/05/2010 22:03:15 Microsoft Word[697] *** -[NSCFString _getValue:forType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17a82b50 
03/05/2010 22:03:15 [0x0-0x51051].com.microsoft.Word[697] Ignoring Quickdraw drawing between QDBeginCGContext and QDEndCGContext 
03/05/2010 22:03:16 [0x0-0x51051].com.microsoft.Word[697] Ignoring Quickdraw drawing between QDBeginCGContext and QDEndCGContext 
03/05/2010 22:03:16 [0x0-0x51051].com.microsoft.Word[697] Ignoring Quickdraw drawing between QDBeginCGContext and QDEndCGContext 
03/05/2010 22:03:16 [0x0-0x51051].com.microsoft.Word[697] Ignoring Quickdraw drawing between QDBeginCGContext and QDEndCGContext 
03/05/2010 22:03:16 [0x0-0x51051].com.microsoft.Word[697] Ignoring Quickdraw drawing between QDBeginCGContext and QDEndCGContext 
03/05/2010 22:03:16 [0x0-0x51051].com.microsoft.Word[697] Ignoring Quickdraw drawing between QDBeginCGContext and QDEndCGContext 
03/05/2010 22:03:17 [0x0-0x51051].com.microsoft.Word[697] 
Mon May  3 22:03:17 leopards-imac-2.local Word[697] <Error>: The function `CGPDFDocumentGetMediaBox' is obsolete 
      and will be removed in an upcoming update. Unfortunately, this application, or a library it uses, is using 
      this obsolete function, and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system performance. 
      Please use `CGPDFPageGetBoxRect' instead. 
03/05/2010 22:22:09 Microsoft Word[697] *** -[NSCFString _getValue:forType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b036500
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to System Preferences > Print & Fax and delete and then re-add the print queue for your printer. If that doesn't work, ctrl-click or right-click on the list of printer queues and select "Reset printing system...".